# Core Data не сохраняется число

Tags: macos, xcode, binding, coredata, objective-c

Здравствуйте! Создал простенькую программку с поддержкой Core Data, типа Document–Based app. Имеется текстовое поле, соединённое с arrayController'ом, который в свою очередь соединён с Entity, у которой есть атрибут "name" типа "string" и атрибут "score" типа "decimal". Введённая в текстовое поле строка сохраняется без проблем.

Также имеется другое текстовое поле: в него вводится число и после нажатия кнопки "Go" значение из поля передаётся в метку. Метка соединена абсолютно точно так же как и первое текстовое поле, но почему-то значение метки не сохраняется.

С чем это связано и как это исправить?
Для наглядности, проект можно скачать отсюда: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kfp61xu3i4zj3kz/QCnPtlVqtE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что "запись" в базу не происходит.
Изыскания показали, что данные из TextField записываются в базу только после переключения "фокуса" из этой TextField в другое место. А у вас получается, что фокусировки нет совсем.

Попробуйте дополнить код "принудительно" записю данных в Базу.

Например:

```
- (IBAction)changeScore:(id)sender {
[_scoreLabel setDoubleValue:[_scoreField doubleValue]];
id saveObj = [_arrayController selectedObjects][0];
double newDob = [_scoreField doubleValue];
NSNumber * decim = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:newDob];
[saveObj setValue:decim forKey:@"score"];
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, это помогло. Вы не могли бы мне разъяснить следующее: насколько я понимаю, в Базу сохраняется только arrayController, но в данном коде он не изменяется. Почему тогда это срабатывает? Или сохраняются все создаваемые объекты, в том числе и saveObj?

Comment: Не совсем, Главное помнить, что все Array объекты - пассивны. То есть они не отслеживают состояние значений (ячеек и т.д.), за актуализацию отвечают обычно другие функции.
Вот и в вашем случае - за обновление name отвечает делега uitextfield, который при "расфокусировке" передает (записывает) значение в Array. А при score - вы не задействовали ниодной функции. saveObj исправляет эту ситуацию.
Сам по себе newObj и saveObj не сохраняются, это переменные, они "удаляются" системой как только перестают быть нужны, а их значения передаются в CoreData

Comment: И еще: NSTextField - передает только NSString, в любом случае пришлось бы писать "конвертор" :), что (опять же) и делает saveObj

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь всё ясно.